# Plotting x axes with increasing and decreasing x-values in R

Tags: r, plot

I have been trying to plot `x axes` with increasing and the decreasing data values in `R`

i.e `x-axes` have values from `[60 to 90 to 60]`, corresponding to different `y-values`

how can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean something like `x1<-c(60:90);x2<-c(90:60);x3<-c(x1,x2);
y<-c(1:62);plot(y ~ x3)`? Or do you want the left and right most extents of the x axis to both correspond to 60?

Comment: not really end points corresponding to 60 but i meant the x values are repeated with different corresponding values of y. example: x = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 and y- 4,5,6,7,8,11,12,23,45,25,11,16,2,3(any value for corresponding y axes). the issue is x values are repeated in ascending and descending order kind of. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an exact answer but you can use `ggplot()` and `facet_wrap` to achieve something similar:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(gridExtra)


# GGPLOT2
x = c(1:50, 50:1)
y = x + rnorm(1000)
group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 50)

df <- data.frame(x, y, group)

p1 <- df %>% 
  filter(group == "A") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = "A")) + geom_point() + ggtitle("UP") + guides(color = F)

p2 <- df %>% 
  filter(group == "B") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = "B")) + geom_point() + scale_x_reverse() + ggtitle("DOWN") + guides(color = F)

grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow = 1)
```

Recently the **plotly** package has been receiving a lot of attention. You could do the following using `ploy_ly()`:

```
# PLOTLY
library(plotly)

p <- df %>% 
  filter(group == "A") %>% 
  plot_ly(x = x, y = y, mode = "markers") %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(domain = c(0, 0.5)))

p <- df %>% 
  filter(group == "A") %>% 
  add_trace(p, x = x, y = y, mode = "markers", xaxis = "x2", yaxis = "y2", data = .) %>% 
  layout(xaxis2 = list(autorange = "reversed",
                       domain = c(0.5, 1)),
         yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y",
                       side = "right"))
p
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
y = c(4,5,6,7,8,11,12,23,45,25,11,16,2)
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:length(x), y))+
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = as.character(x))
```

[image]

This will not work so well if `x` is not in the proper order or has missing values. You should consider adding a MWE along with your attempts in your question.

Comment: this is great, it helped me out